# How to select a particular row of query result

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a following table in my Oracle database:

[image]

How can I select the course which is done by most of the students?
I am trying multiple variations in following SQL query but it's not working -

```
select count(course) as pcourse, course 
from studies 
group by course 
order by pcourse dec;
```

Comment: Try with top 1. First order the query such that the wanted row is on top, then with top 1 you get only this one

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an Oracle DB, i think the following should work

```
SELECT * FROM
(select count(course) as pcourse, course 
from studies 
group by course 
order by pcourse dec)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

> Reply to the Comment

That's because rownum is **assigned sequentially** to the rows that are **returned**.

So let's say you put ROWNUM = 2, your query will return the first row, and temporarily give it rownum of 1. But since it does not match the condition ROWNUM = 2, it will be *discarded*. Then it will go on to fetch the second row, and give it also rownum 1, and the cycle continues.

If you want to get the Nth row, you could probably do this

```
SELECT pcourse, course FROM
(select count(course) as pcourse, course, rownum as rn 
from studies 
group by course 
order by pcourse dec)
WHERE rn = N
```

where N is the required row.

Comment: rownum is a keyword in Oracle. each row in the resultset is assigned a unique row number, rownum

Comment: I am learning it, don't like it :) I prefer my top 1 (sql-server) because it can be done all in one select instead of an inner select and outer select....

Comment: @aakashgupta.0205 Thanks Aakash, its working.But I am surprised why is doesn't give second row or say third row when we give ROWNUM=2 or ROWNUM=3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `rownum`, which is Oracle's equivalent of `TOP 1` (from SQL Server) or `LIMIT 1` (from MySQL).

```
select *
from 
    (select count(course) as pcourse
        , course
    from studies
    group by course
    order by pcourse desc) result_set
where rownum = 1
```

It is important that you use `where rownum = 1` in a higher level `SELECT` because Oracle requires you to first sort the result set and then it will filter the rows.

Otherwise, if you would include the `where rownum = 1` condition in the same level as the `SELECT` with which you get your data, then it will be immediately be filtering to 1 row (the first it finds) and sorting it (which won't make any sense, since it will only be one row).

As per *@a_horse_with_no_name*'s comment, apparently Oracle gives you the possibility to write a `TOP 1` filtering condition in the same level `SELECT`, like below:

```
select count(course) as pcourse
    , course
from studies
group by course
order by pcourse desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: @Matt `TOP 1` is SQL Server syntax, won't work in Oracle (yet).

Comment: ahh oracle..... rownum is a key word got it after searching.  wow that makes the query an inner select and more of a pain....

Comment: @Matt Yes, well.. that's one of the first things I learned when switching to Oracle from SQL Server and I agree, it's a little more code to write, but in time you will embrace Oracle (it's not like you have to write a ton more of code).

Comment: @Matt: Oracle supports the ANSI SQL `fetch 1 rows first`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the input (still learning..)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu fair enough, I am definitely a little more pigeon holed into sql-server these days but I learn every day thanks for the tips!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thanks mate, that's great help. I tried with ROWNUM and its working fine but surprised that it doesn't give you second record when you give ROWNUM=2. Also, fetch first 1 rows only/fetch 1 rows first syntax not working.

Comment: @user286009 For what you want you need to change it to <= 2 order by desc and rownum = 1 again. I know it's cumbersome, but that's how Oracle has this working.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu yes I got your point. I tried this -                          select * from 
(select *
    from 
    (select count(course) as pcourse
        , course
    from studies
    group by course
    order by pcourse desc) result_set
where rownum <= 2 order by pcourse asc) result_set2 where rownum=1 ;        and got second row.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work but I haven't created your test data because it is in a picture, please include as text next time

```
SELECT
   course
   ,COUNT(*) AS pcourse
FROM
   Studies
GROUP BY
   course
ORDER BY
   COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

I am still a little unsure of how to the fetch first row/select top 1/limit 1 for Oracle but @a-horse_with_no_name is teaching and I am learning so here is stab at it.  here is a link for Oracles syntax on `offest` and `fetch` http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html